# How to bring nested array of items in table format using ng-repat in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to bring the table of items for each location using ng-repeat. I can't get around it using ng-repeat for the following structure. Please someone help me. Thanks in Advance.

The structure is.

```
$scope.locations = [
// Location #1
  [
    {
      location:"location1",
      delar:"delar-x",
      items:[
        {
          name:"Iphone",
          price:124
        },
        {
          name:"Blackbery",
          price:132
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      location:"location1",
      delar:"delar-y",
      items:[
        {
          name:"Headphone",
          price:10
        },
        {
          name:"Cabels",
          price:112
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  // Location #2
  [
    {
      location:"location2",
      delar:"delar-x",
      items:[
        {
          name:"Iphone",
          price:124
        },
        {
          name:"Blackbery",
          price:132
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      location:"location2",
      delar:"delar-y",
      items:[
        {
          name:"Headphone",
          price:120
        },
        {
          name:"Cabels",
          price:110
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
]
```

How would i bring the following format?

```
<div>
  <h1> location1 </h1>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td> Iphone </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Blackbery </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Headphone </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Cabels </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <h1> location2 </h1>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td> Iphone </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Blackbery </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Headphone </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Cabels </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
<div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can follow a two step approach

```
<div>
    <h1 ng-repeat-start="loc in locs"> {{loc.location}} </h1>

    <table ng-repeat-end>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in loc.items">
            <td>{{item.name}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

then normalize the locations array

```
$scope.locations = [....];

//normalize the locations array to a format which can be easily iterated using ng-repeat
var map = {}, array=[];
angular.forEach($scope.locations, function(obj){
    angular.forEach(obj, function(obj){
        var items = map[obj.location];
        if(!items){
            items = map[obj.location] = [];
            array.push({
                location: obj.location,
                items:items
            })
        }
        console.log(obj)
        angular.forEach(obj.items, function(item){
            items.push(item);
        })
    });
})
$scope.locs = array;
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Qa7nS/)